# Can contracts define all the invariants a type system does?

Tags: types

I've never really programmed with a design by contract language and I certainly don't want this post to become a war on dynamic vs static typed systems.

My question after reading a while is the one in the title: everything a type system can "catch", can also a design by contract?
In some sites I've read things like "contracts are types on steroids", and claims like that. But is it really a true superset?

Or put in other way, can a dynamic language with contracts have the same and more verification (again, at runtime) than a statically typed language without them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Only *local* properties can be checked dynamically, whereas properties that require some kind of *global* knowledge cannot. Think of properties such as something being unique, something not being aliased, a computation being free of race conditions or dead locks. A suitable static type system can verify such properties, because it has the ability to establish certain invariants on the context of the expression that is being checked.

Comment: So if I have not misunderstood you... having contracts helps in detecting where a thing went wrong locally (and at run-time) and static type checking can tell us more information on global errors and other kind of errors which can't be proved dynamically. Is that it? If so I see now how these two concepts differ. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well, yes, for the right definition of "local error". Of course, you could arguably regard some code using a pointer and assuming it's not aliased, while it actually may be, as a "local" error. But it's one you can only identify as an error when you have more global knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert in contracts, but I think this is mostly correct. In general, contracts allow you to write dynamic checks that enforce arbitrarily complex behavior.  The cool thing about contracts is that you can use them to:

- specify behavior a type system *can't* catch.  (For the *usual* definitions of type systems.)
- Include them in your programs at runtime to get a detailed report of what goes wrong.
- Assign, track, and propagate *blame* to see what went wrong, and where.

Yes, a contract can be as simple as a type system, in the sense that the common viewpoint of "types as sets" (which is not really correct in the polymorphic cse, but approximates some behavior for many cases you'll care about) can be viewed as a *structural* constraint of a contract language.  However, contract systems allow you to write much more embellished behavior.  While you can write a contract to express the relationship between a sorting function's input and it's sorted output, this would require a *dependent type* if written down correctly in types.  So the simple answer is, yes, contracts can be used to define everything a type system can, and more.  (I'm not entirely sure about the edge cases for things like strange substructural type systems, but I think this could also be accomplished by contracts that taint things.)

The flip side of the coin is that type systems give you static *guarentees* that your program is -- to some extent -- correct.  While, with a contract, you really can't say this at all.  (Of course, you could view certain degenerate cases of contracts as being partially verified by use of a standard type system, model checking, SMT solver, etc..., and some work has indeed been done in this area.)  However, the really powerful thing about contracts is basically the idea that program verification is hard, let's throw away some of the static guarantees, live with some possible bugs, and get better information about what went wrong so we can fix it quickly.

By the way, there are much more advanced contract systems now, beyond just simple structural constraints, there are also things like higher order temporal contracts ([here](http://users.soe.ucsc.edu/~cormac/papers/icfp11.pdf)), and other extensions that make programming with contracts very cool.

edit:  I suppose I should have made this more clear too, there are certainly local properties of your programs which you can't track globally with contracts, so Andres' response seems more correct in that regard to me, sorry about that!

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer. I just wanted to be sure about it. In fact, the work done on contracts seems promising from my noobie point of view, although there's a tradeoff as more advanced systems will also mean more work devoted to that task instead of the problem itself (but that happens everywhere anyway: correctness VS time). One thing I like, though, is that contracts can generally be "added" to a language (for example a dynamic one) thus leaving the decission to the programmer and not being an implicit characteristic in language (I'm thinking of Python or Clojure + contracts).

Comment: Are there any statically typed languages that also make use of contracts? In case the answer is yes, wouldn't that be a little bit of overhead?

Comment: Checking the contracts statically is impossible for the same reason that any program analysis is computationally impossible: you would have to solve the halting problem to do it.  Therefore, no, typically you write a dependent type, prove your program has that type, and extract a proved correct piece of code, but this isn't automated, you have to write a proof manually.

Comment: I think I didn't expressed that too well. I meant if there's any static typed language which also allows for contracts verification at run-time. I think you thought I was asking if they could be proved at compilation time. Or have I missed something? I suppose having a static type checker at compilation time, and contract at runtime would be a huge security boom, at the cost of more time in designing/programming. Thanks!